# RS485 communication issue

Tags: communication, rs485, protocol, modbus

I have used PIC18F45k40 device for RS485 communication. I have 2 ckts one is isolated and another non isolated RS485 design. I have schematic & placement for reference. I have connected multiple slave device independently isolated and non isolated product , its working well. There is no issue with poll mismatch

Now i am combining isolated and non isolated module in parallel.during this stage, after hour isolated module stop communicating but isolated version product working well.

difference i found in both device i found is voltage level during operation isolated version if measure voltage across A& B w.r.t gnd is 7V-9V respectively i.e for ADM2483(Isolated ground)

where as SN75176 non isolated IC voltage level across A &B w.r.t ground is 2.5V-5V respectively.

i would like to why my communication of isolated version get disturbed when non isolated version is introduced.

which one is better to use to make solve this kind of problems

[sn75176](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75176a.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-sf-df-ds-null-wwe)

Comment: Is the ground reference wire connected between RS485 devices, or only the A and B wires? Where is ADM2483 GND2 connected? From where the products get their power, are those power supplies ground/earth referenced or floating?

Comment: @justme  For ADM2483 i am taking ground reference from transformer. transformer which give 12V/GND1 and 5V/gnd2. i have converted 12VDC to 5V using 7805 regulator IC.  Isolated and non Isolated module are two independent product each will get power from Transformer . I am not seeing floating voltage in w.r.t ground. when i tested independent they showing as expected voltage levels. i have tested the unit without ground reference,when i combine.  as product both work on A& B

Comment: So they do not have common reference? Then, in addition to connecting A and B between tranceivers, also connect GND2 of isolated tranceiver with the GND of the other tranceiver. See if it fixes the issue. RS485 does not work without common reference between tranceivers.

Comment: I have read few article. where there is non isolated design we no need to use GND. if we using isolated RS485 ckt we should provide common ground reference. Using isolated gnd ckts are always safer to use. since voltage level are 7V-12V.  but my confusion is non isolated version has 5V output across A&B w.r.t gnd . But where as isolated version gives 7-12V w.r.t its ground. why 5V o/p non isolated module affect isolated version

Comment: Either the articles you've read are wrong or you've misunderstood them. You must have a common/ground connection between your RS485 transceivers. In a non-isolated system it is possible (but not guaranteed) that this common ground connection travels through the power supply on each side and through mains earth.

Comment: If the isolated GND2 of ADM2483 comes from a floating power supply, it has extremely high impedance and any stray capacitance in the power supply transformer could make the GND2 voltage to have tens of volts AC compared to the other device. Which is why ground wire is needed to make GND2 to be at same potential as the other device tranceiver GND.

Comment: I'd like to second what the others have said. You can have biasing resistors at every node, but they should not be very strong... in terms of providing a proper signal reference GND potential, nothing beats a proper third conductor or shield in the signal cable. That takes care of any parasitic RF coupling in DC-DC converters isolating your transceivers, Y-cap leakage etc. http://support.fccps.cz/download/adv/frr/RS485/RS485.html  If you can get an oscilloscope to look at your signals, by all means do so. Very educational.

Comment: BTW having 7-12 Volts against ref.gnd at a transceiver powered by 5V can only signal one thing: that your ref.GND link to the neighbor nodes is not very solid, or the distance and loop area are not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, there are only the differential data wires A and B connected between the two RS485 tranceivers that do not share a common reference, as one of the tranceivers includes isolation and runs on separate isolated power supply, so it completely floats in regards to the other tranceiver and the voltages float more than the common mode range allows for.

RS485 tranceivers must share a common voltage reference, and this is why there should be a common wire between tranceiver, that connects the ground of isolated RS485 tranceiver to ground of the other tranceiver, so they have a common reference potential.

Comment: thanks for all valuable Input . Let me try making all ground common . weather any variation observed in system.. Meanwhile I would like to know when we should use isolated /non-isolated ground design. performance wise which design is better?